# PHP unlink file works only sometimes

Tags: php, windows, permissions, xampp, unlink

When using the php function unlink() sometimes the file is not deleted and I get a permission denied error message. This is strange, because sometimes it is working.
I am working local with xampp on Windows. Do you have an idea why this keeps happening?

Comment: Are you working on the same directory everytime or different?

Comment: It is always the same directory and file.

Comment: How is the file created? Is it created by the same process (and the same user) that is trying to delete it? What permissions does the file have when this fails? Are you trying to delete from a Xampp/Apache process?

Comment: I use the library PHPExcel and create the file with ' $xls = new PHPExcel();
    $xls->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($results, NULL, 'A1');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xls, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('filename.xls');'

Answer (score 0):

I think the file needs to have the permissions.

Comment: Yeah that also came to my mind when the error message said 'permission denied'... But why is it working sometimes and sometimes not?

Comment: its possible that you have not close a "fopen()" ?